# Can I shrink a SQL database log file via file path / by using it's self?

Tags: sql-server

I am designing a program which shrinks database log files across a network.

The log file will not always be in the same format so I want to shrink it via the path name. To get the path names at the moment I am writing:

```
select top 2 physical_name as current_file_location FROM sys.master_files where physical_name like '%adventureworks%'
```

My script to shrink the log files are:

```
ALTER DATABASE adventureworks2012 SET RECOVERY SIMPLE DBCC 
SHRINKFILE ('c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.50\MSSQL\DATA\adventureworks2012_log.ldf', 1) 
ALTER DATABASE adventureworks2012 SET RECOVERY FULL
```

This returns the error:

> Could not locate file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10.50\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorksLog.ldf' for database
>   'AdventureWorks' in sys.database_files. The file either does not
>   exist, or was dropped.

Is there a way I can make it select its self regardless of log file naming convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to grab the ID from the original select list and use that to shrink it by.

`select top 2 file_id, physical_name as current_file_location FROM sys.master_files where physical_name like '%adventureworks%'`

then in my second script:

`DBCC SHRINKFILE (2,1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @string Varchar(8000), @Strt Int ,@End Int
  select name INto #tt from  sys.databases where is_read_only=0 and state=0
  and name  NOT In ('master','model','tempdb','msdb')

  Select ROW_NUMBER()Over(Order by Name)SRNO,name INto #TTT from #tt
  Set @Strt=1
  Select @End=Max(Srno)from #ttt

  While @Strt<=@End
    Begin
        Declare @Db Varchar(255),@str varchar(Max)
        Select @Db=Name from #ttT Where Srno=@Strt
        Set @str=''
        Select  @str= 'ALTER DATABASE '''+Name+''' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE' from #tTt Where Srno=@Strt 
        --Exec (@str)
        DBCC shrinkdatabase (@Db)
        Print @Db
        Set @Strt=@Strt+1
    End

Drop Table  #tt
Drop Table  #ttT
```

Comment: From this Script you will be able to Shrink Log File in SQL Server 2012 And Above.

Comment: Will this just shrink the log file??

Comment: @SCramphorn no, as it's a call to `SHRINKDATABASE` rather than `SHRINKFILE`

Comment: @SCramphon Yes you will be Able to Shrink the Log File